# Android Video Calling feature using wifi

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to implement video calling using wifi feature?
I have tried Intent for it but its not working.Please help me out.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
            callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
            callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+919167903192"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Video calling like Skype requires using the SIP protocol. Good thing, there is `android.net.sip`. Bad thing, it only supports VoIP out of the box.

What's the way out?
You need to use a SIP library like `JAIN SIP` or `CSipSimple` to get the work done. You will also need a SIP provider. You can either become one or use an existing one like `GetOnSip`.

My point being?
It is not as easy as using an intent. You will have to do the manual coding.